# Quick prototyping tool to consume REST API results on the web

Tags: xml, jquery-ui, rest

I am interested in writing an HTML5 application that consumes REST APIs. I am wondering if there are interesting tools that can help me prototype a UI really quickly?

For example is it easy to consume REST api's in jQuery? are there other tools/libraires that make it easier.

Something like [dashcode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004692-CH1-SW2) for Linux or windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the UI prototype there are tools like

1. Balsamiq http://www.balsamiq.com/
2. JustinMindPrototyper http://www.justinmind.com/

Otherwise some great ideas come from Ryan Singer's (37Signals UI guy) talk  on "Design and Prototyping"  http://feltpresence.com/   The interesting point is that some of the UI prototype tools create a high-fidelity version, when in fact if you are trying to design and get an interative/agile process going then a low-fidelity prototype works best.